# Failing to connect to MongoDB hosted on mlab

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mlab

## Background

Making a small web app that connects to a Mongo DB hosted with [Mlab](https://mlab.com/). I've created the DB on mlab, and created users with read/write permission. I've also created a `users` collection with several records.

## The Problem

When I try and connect to the database using the code on [mongo.github.io](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/tutorials/connect/), I hit the error:

```
/home/ed/dev/mongo-demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/mongo_client_ops.js:466
      throw err;
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'db' of null
```

## The Code

```js
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const url = 'mongodb://<user>:<pass>@ds115434.mlab.com:15434';

// Database Name
const dbName = 'princee3-music';

// Use connect method to connect to the server
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client) {
  console.log("Connected successfully to server");

  const db = client.db(dbName);

  client.close();
});
```

## What I Have Tried

Oddly, if I connect through the shell using:

```
mongo ds115434.mlab.com:15434/princee3-music -u <dbuser> -p <dbpassword>
```

That works fine, or if I wrap the connection in an anonymous self-calling async function, it also connects.

## Async Wrapper

```js
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const mongoUrl = 'mongodb://<user>:<pass>@ds115434.mlab.com:15434/';
const dbName = 'princee3-music';

(async() => {
   const client = await MongoClient.connect(mongoUrl, { useNewUrlParser: true});
   const db = client.db(dbName);
   db.collection('users').insertOne({
     email: user.email,
     pass: hashedPassword,
     admin: true
   }, (err, result) => {
     if (err) {
       reject({error: err});
     } else {
       resolve({message: 'okay'});
     }
   });
   client.close();
 })();
```

Any pointers on where I may be going wrong would be great.

Comment: Can you please give me the output of `console.log(err)` to be placed above `const db = client.db(dbName)`?

Comment: `{ MongoError: Authentication failed.`

Comment: Why are you not satisfied with async? It makes sense to wait for the connection to effectively occur before doing anything in there...

Answer (score 1):

The official mLab docs advise to connect like below. It has to be asynchronous , in order to wait for the connection to occur, or the client will be null, thus throwing an error saying that it can’t read property db of null.

On the other hand, you async has `useNewUrlParser` which might be the key to have a successful connection, see [this issue](https://github.com/typeorm/mongo-typescript-example/issues/1)

```
MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }).then(client => client.db())
```

Comment: Still getting an authentication error when trying this way

Comment: @EdPrince I have edited the answer, you may need `useNewUrlParser` depending on the version

Comment: Tried, and still the same authentication failed

Comment: @EdPrince if you guarantee that your async wrapper works then the only remaining difference is the trailing slash at the end of your mongoUrl. For the rest I can’t help any further sorry

Comment: So it turns out you have to add the db name to the end of the URI, I hadn't realised that